# why the output of this program is wrong?.Frequency of number

Tags: c

Program for the frequency of a number
Please help me with this code to get clear output. I am a beginner
I have made the program using an array. I don't know whether it is correct or not. Made with my own logic

```
int count(int a)  
{  
    int c;    
    while(a>=1)  
    {  
        c++;  
        a=a/10;  
    }  
    return c;  
}
int main()   
{  
     //program to find frquency of the number  
     int a,n,d;  
     int b[100];  
     int e[100];  
     scanf("%d",&a);
     n=count(a);

     for(int i=n;a>0;i--)     
     {
        b[i]=a%10; 
        a=a/10;
     }
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
     {

        d=b[i];
        e[d]++;//most probably this part error occurs
        printf("%d\n",d); //used this this to confirm that i have correctly stored value in d.
     }

      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
     {

        printf("%d ",e[i]);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect the program to return, and what did it actually return?

Comment: `c` ain't initialised for staters.

Comment: It seems you haven't tried [running your program using a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); you should do that.

Comment: neither is `e` (initialized)

Comment: My input is 12345                                                                                                                            Actual output 35286 25471 21456  52614 25325                                                                                                             Expected output 11111 to display the frequency of the number in this series. Please help me as I am a beginner. @Venantius

Comment: Please provide your input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: I have intialized it as int e[100] @SanderDeDycker

Comment: Initialise `c` as 0 in the `count()` and all indexes of `e` with 0 before using them.

Comment: @zeeshan That's *defined*, not initialized. `int e[100] = {0};` to zero-fill that array (or use a loop). yours contains *indeterminate* values, and as such it's content is *undefined*. A *debugger* an examining the content of `e` *before* entering the loop would make the problem I'm describing clearer. Get one (a debugger).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you! It worked.you are great.Used this:int e[100] = {0};

Comment: A couple of hints. In an array such as `e[100]` a valid array index will have a value of 0 to 99 inclusive, and every element of that array should be set to 0 before use. Also, it isn't necessary to store the digits in any particular order—you can do whatever's most convenient. Additionally, there are only 10 digits, so a counter of digit frequency should probably be an array of size 10. Finally, make sure your code works with numbers such as `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line `int c;` should be `int c = 0;`
2. The line `int e[100];` should be `int e[100] = {0};`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int a) {
  int c = 0;
  while (a >= 1) {
    c++;
    a = a / 10;
  }
  return c;
}
int main() {
  // program to find frquency of the number
  int a, n, d;
  int b[100];
  int e[100] = {0};
  scanf("%d", &a);
  n = count(a);

  for (int i = n; a > 0; i--) {
    b[i] = a % 10;
    a = a / 10;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    d = b[i];
    e[d]++;             // most probably this part error occurs
    printf("%d\n", d);  // used this this to confirm that i have correctly
                        // stored value in d.
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", e[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also, you can do it use `snprintf`:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      int a;
      int max = -1;
      char buf[100];
      int count[10] = {0};

      scanf("%d", &a);
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", a);

      for (int i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int temp = buf[i] - '0';
        ++count[temp];
        if (temp > max)
          max = temp;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i)
        printf("%d ", count[i]);

      return 0;
    }
```